# Create BoxPlot in R with PreSummarized Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have aggregated cost data that is already summarized. I do not have access to the raw data. I have the mean, standard deviation, median, and IQR. The data looks like this:

[image]

I would like to create boxplots in R using this data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to handle the whiskers?  Usually, they extend on the low end to the larger of the minimum value of the data and  Q1-1.5*(Q3-Q1)  and on the high end to the smaller of the maximum of the data or Q3 + 1.5*(Q3-Q1).  You could calculate the quartiles +/- 1.5*(Q3-Q1), but without knowing the minimum and maximum in the data, the whiskers might be too long.

Comment: I do not want the whiskers if that is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Mean_Cost = c(300, 760, 500), 
  Std = c(20,55,100), 
  Median_Cost = c(200, 222, 467), 
  LowerIQR = c(150, 100, 333), 
  UpperIQR = c(220, 300, 500), 
  Group = c(1,2,3))


ggplot(dat, aes(xmin = Group-.25, xmax=Group+.25, ymin=LowerIQR, ymax=UpperIQR)) + 
  geom_rect(fill="transparent", col = "black") + 
  geom_segment(aes(y=Median_Cost, yend=Median_Cost, x=Group-.25, xend=Group+.25)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:3, labels=c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group 3")) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  labs(x="", y="Cost")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I do want to add in a line/mark where the mean is - is this a simple extra line in the code?